# openFDA: Can we print results for multiple patients at once?

Tags: api, openfda

Is there any way to get multiple patients' results in one output? I've noticed it defaults to show one patient's results at a time - and skipping allows you to see other patients - but is there any way to have two or more show up in one result (e.g. change the limit of a "results" search)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `limit` URL parameter which maxes out at a value of 100.

For example: [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:[2012-08-09+TO+3000-01-01]&limit=100](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate%3a%5b2012-08-09+TO+3000-01-01%5d&limit=100)

This is explained at the "Query parameters" section of the API documentation at https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to search and filter through results, check out [ResearchAE.com](http://www.researchae.com/) which I built for non-programmers to be able to search through OpenFDA/FAERS data.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 'ad pan' is, and what features ResearchAE has that might help the person asking the question?  Also, if you have an affiliation with ResearchAE, please mention it.