# Getting more than 100 records from OpenFDA in MS Excel

Tags: api, openfda, excel

I have a query that appears to identify 975 items per the meta information.  I used the limit (100)  & skip (25) parameters to get the result.  However, if I try to use that same query in Excel (see below) to pull the results it appears to ignore the limit & skip parameters and therefore only returns the 100 based on the limit or 1 if no limit is specified. Is there a way to get ALL 975 items?  The URL I am using is:

```
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=device.generic_name:%22LAPAROSCOPIC+MORCELLATOR%22+AND+device_report_product_code:HET&limit=100&skip=25
```

I am following some of the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-FhPq_0N0M) to use powerquery to create a worksheet in Excel.

Comment: This has been answered in http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/openfda-can-we-print-results-for-multiple-patients-at-once (see the first answer).

Comment: thank you.  i understand that there is a limit as well as skip.  however unless i am mistaken the limit has a maximum of 100 and skip does not appear to have any impact if pulling the result via ms/excel.

Comment: I edited your title to make it clear that your problem is related to MS Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the limit is now 1000 with an API key. Try getting and adding an API key and changing the limit to 1000